# How many of the primes can be subdivided into concatenations of smaller primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion

How many of the primes (as in how many per cent) are concatenations (let us write $\oplus$ as the symbol for concatenation) of some other strictly smaller primes (in basis 10)? ( We are free to choose any split of the digits ).

For example

$$53 = 5 \oplus 3\\
743 = 7 \oplus 43\\
523 = 5\oplus 23$$

But $1103$ is not since $0$ is not a prime ( and say we choose to not allow numbers starting with $0$ as in $03$ )

Comment: Is this https://oeis.org/A104179 or slightly different? I think it's the same

Comment: @AakashM They are not the same. For instance $541=5\oplus41$ is not in A104179. In fact it is [A105184](https://oeis.org/A105184)

Comment: @JuliánAguirre right you are. I was foolishly searching for sequences starting 2 3 5 7 23 37, having failed to properly read the question...